# Error Running VBS to Mail Merge with Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, mailmerge, vba

I have setup a simple VBS to open .xlsm file that has a macro to open a word doc and execute mail merge. VBS works great until I try to automate it with Task Scheduler.

Excel macro was running with both Excel and Word instances open but it took way longer than it supposed to be with couple Excel error message :

```
Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action
```

And after couple of error message and long wait for word doc to go through all records, mail merge was not executed at all.

Does anyone have similar experience with me? Any resolution/suggestion is highly appreciated.